# What is the main difference between Agile Software Development & Extreme Programming?

Tags: project-management, agile, extreme-programming

Title has it. Just to have an idea, pointing to some good links with documentations are good enough.

Comment: XP is agile software development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP is a specific kind of agile development, Scrum being another well-known specific variant. These days it's more common to simply say you're using "agile methods" in general, and pick and choose from a range of agile practices.